# How to tell if a door is locked just by looking

Tags: home, door

There are times when I am running out the door, but I remember that I may have forgotten to lock one of my doors. Nearly 3/4 of the time, I did lock it but I have to waste time going back and checking. I can see the lock from where I leave from, but I can't make out the details of if it is turned or not. **Is there any hack for checking if a door is locked just by looking?**

This is the type of lock that I have (its a deadbolt I believe)

[image: deadbolt lock]

Comment: Learn which way the knob is turned that makes it locked. On the doors in my house, the flat part should be horizontal. Other houses have it vertical. That's the only way I know of.

Comment: If you can see the lock you should be able to tell if it is locked, especially if it has a large winged knob. Maybe walk a little closer and look?

Comment: @Quincunx Frustratingly, my two doors aren't consistent; one horizontal and one vertical. Memorization works where UX fails.

Comment: @Geobits - I'm vaguely curious... Does my comment on the accepted answer apply to your two different doors?

Comment: @KevinStricker On the vertically-locked one it does. The other one has the screws diagonal, so they're not covered in either position.

Comment: Inconvenient...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply add a couple of stickers or markings on the twisty thing that would make you know if it is in the correct position or not, it would make it easier to identify from a distance away whether or not it is locked without having to try the handle.

If I am mistaken and I have misunderstood what your lock looks like and where you are trying to determine its locked state from (i.e. Outside the house and the knob is on the inside) then I apologise and that last bit is of little to no use for you. However, it you get in the habit of doing something unusual when you lock your door, like a body movement or shouting or something, then it will make it much easier to remember whether or not you have locked it once you've walked away.

Comment: Related: To accomodate installation, the knob on the inside is often centered between the screws in the plate when unlocked and askew/covering one or more of them when locked.

Answer (score 2):

You can rig a little red LED on the door. You will need to dismantle the lock, which is easy, by taking out the two screws. Mount a battery, and micro switch within the cavity. Position the switch so it turns off when the lock is engaged. Drill a small hole to insert the LED so it will be visible from the desired direction. Flashing LEDs are also available, too!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most doors, if you look on the inside, have a nub that locks into the side of your door. If it's in the hole it's locked. Of course, not all doors are like that. Sorry if your door is different.